# Wordpress get short code link from content

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi I was just wondering if there is a way to get the inside of the [embed][/embed] shortcode. I tried this method but to no prevail:. thanks

```
$argsabc = extract( shortcode_atts( array(
    'embed' => ''
), $this->post['post_content'] ) );
```

Comment: Not clear with your query, can you please explain it to bit more.

Comment: in the post_content there is a short code with a youtube link like this [embed]http://www.youtube.com/?v=videourl[/embed] what i need is the link inside it

Comment: Ok Got it. Let me give you the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 get_shortcode_regex()
```

Please use this to get it done. Hope it will work for you.
More Info :http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_shortcode_regex

Comment: Its great to hear that.